# Offsetting flames and/or smoke from the emitter

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've tried a few times to get emitted smoke and fire to appear slightly offset from the emitter, like for example a gas weld or a flamethrower. I've played with vorticity, temperature difference, density, speed, flame rate and practically every other setting whose name even remotely indicates that it may make a difference. All to no avail. I've also tried to add wind with various strengths and directions, and making a larger portion of the fire colour ramp transparent.

As you can see in this image, Suzanne emits fire from her eyes and whatever that heart shape is meant to represent (mouth or nose?).
[image: Suzanne spewing fire]

I want a small gap before the flame actually appears, similar to what can be seen here.
[image: Flamethrower]

How, if at all, can this be achieved? I'm using BI.

Blend file for the Suzanne image: http://pasteall.org/blend/33192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making a fake emmitter. Basically an object that has faces where you want the smoke emmited.

Comment: That is, of course, an option. However, I was hoping it could be done without adding more faces. I will consider it though. I upvoted, and I'll accept if, after experimenting further, no other solution magically appears.